# Unable to iterate over json object in node , express application

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, mean

This is my jade code

```
block content
    .container
        #{data} //prints the whole json doc
        p Here the list of topics will be shown
        for topic,index in data
                p #{index}#{topic.title}
```

There are continue indexes till 1002 displayed after "*Here the list of topics will be shown*". But no there is no data alongside index shown.

This is my json data which gets printed by `#{data}`

```
[{"_id":"56cc8af53ce0def08a1fa4fa","title":"Rotational Motion","subtopics":[{"stitle":"Introduction","versions":[{"desc":"What is rotational motion?"},{"desc":"Describe it?"}]},{"stitle":"Defination","versions":[{"desc":"Define rotational motion"},{"desc":"Define Rotational motion in detail"}]},{"stitle":"Derivation","versions":[{"desc":"Define rotational motion"},{"desc":"Define Rotational motion in detail"}]}]},{"_id":"56cc71107bb2a0733aba0007","title":"Wave Motion","subtopics":[{"stitle":"Introduction","versions":[{"desc":"What is rotational motion?"},{"desc":"Describe it?"}]},{"stitle":"Defination","versions":[{"desc":"Define rotational motion"},{"desc":"Define Rotational motion in detail"}]}]},{"_id":"56c635b38aff62a82b245e20","title":"Sound and Light","subtopics":[{"stitle":"Introduction","versions":[{"desc":"What is rotational motion?"},{"desc":"Describe it?"}]},{"stitle":"Defination","versions":[{"desc":"Define rotational motion"},{"desc":"Define Rotational motion in detail"}]}]}]
```

This is how I am rendering the file -

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var options = {
      host: 'someurl',
      port: 80,
      path: '/topics'
    };

    http.get(options, function(webresponse) {
      console.log("Got response: " + webresponse.statusCode);

      webresponse.on("data", function(chunk) {
        console.log("data: " + chunk);
        var data = chunk; 
        console.log(data); //prints the json data correctly
        //rendering html with params
        res.render('index', { user : req.user , data : data });

      });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
      console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jade uses `each` not `for`. Update your code to `each topic in data` and it should work fine.

[Jade Docs](http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/)

EDIT: Going by your server code, it would seem that `data` is simply a JSON object that is returned as a string, that's why you cannot loop it correctly. Using `JSON.parse(data)` before sending it to the renderer should fix that issue

Comment: Even using each is giving same results, nothing is displayed. Where else would I be making a mistake?

Comment: I'm guessing using `p= topic.title` yields the same results? Is the JSON parsed before you send it to JADE, or is it simply a string? You could try `each topic in JSON.parse(data)` and see if that works

Comment: `p = topic.title` is not working. And i have updated question to include how I am rendering the file.

Comment: Ok, have you tried parsing the JSON before rendering? Could be that your web response is returning the JSON as a string (highly likely)

Comment: No, I havent, how should i parse it? `JSON.stringify(data)` like this?